# I need to change the access of my folders that I am creating to be not read only

Tags: permissions

I am creating a folder that is a phone number that people type into a textbox. Then I am creating a text file inside of that folder with the info from the other text boxes, but will not create the text file because the folder it created using the phone number is set to "Read Only".

```
Phonenumber = phonereg_textbox.Text;
FirstName = firstname_textbox.Text;
LastName = lastname_textbox.Text;
Email = email_textbox.Text;
Password = Passwordone; 
DateOFBirth = selectedDate;
//check if the phonenumber exists if it does then show a message, if it does not exist then create
if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\Users\mogee\Desktop\2019Form Files\Registered Users\" + Phonenumber))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\mogee\Desktop\2019Form Files\Registered Users\" + Phonenumber);

    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(@"C:\Users\mogee\Desktop\2019Form Files\Registered Users\" + Phonenumber))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("Hello");
        sw.WriteLine("And");
        sw.WriteLine("Welcome");
    }
    MessageBox.Show("File Created");


    //Close page and open Register Email Sent page
    RegisterEmailSent RES = new RegisterEmailSent();
    RES.Show();
    this.Close();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("File Already Exists");
    RegisterEmailSent RES = new RegisterEmailSent();
    RES.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

I am only getting an error when it tries to create the text file